# A question about tenses and quantifiers

Tags: tense, quantifiers

I have done all my homework = There is no more homework to be done.

I am tired because i have done a lot of homework. "a lot" is a quantity, which requires present perfect simple.

Is it possible to say: I am tired because I have done all my homework? Can "all" be seen as a quantity or does "have done all" always mean that there is nothing left to do?

I am tired because I have been doing my homework. It is the activity that made me tired, so present perfect continuous is used. Can the continuous be used with a quantity, for example:
I am tired because I have been doing all my homework, or lots of homework?

Comment: "I am tired after doing all of my homework" seems to sound closer to "I am tired because I have done a lot of homework" than "I am tired because I have done all my homework".

Comment: Is "I am tired because i have done all my homework" ideomatic?

Comment: It sounds weird to me, since "I have done all my homework" has a positive feeling to it. "I am happy because I have done all my homework!" would work, or "I am happy because I have finished all my homework!". "I am tired because I have just finished all my homework." seems to work too colloquially.

Comment: So "I am tired because I have done all my homework" is strange, but "I am tired because I have just finished all my homework"is okay?

Comment: It sounds right to me, but I'm not sure what the grammatical reason is.